# how to text with image share on intent in android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, whatsapp

I want to share image with text via intent. not a image whole or text differtent. see this is my code:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
        + "/drawable/app_icon");

String shareTxt = "Hey, now this is image "+ imageUri + " text.";

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareTxt);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
```

Output: I need to : "Text IMAGE text"

but actually out put this: image whole below text coming.

So, android people help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lots of search and finally found for myself solution this is encoding string put and get the image with text and sharing. So very thanks for me.

See this link and get the encode format of image string.
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2702/index.htm